# Spring Web Service REST API JSON response always includes boolean values

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-security

I am using Spring web services REST API that gives the JSON response.

**The API usage:**

```
    @ResponseBody
    @RequestMapping(value="/user", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
    Details user(@RequestParam("username") 
    String username, @RequestParam("password") String password)
```

**The JSON coming is:**

```
{
  "result":{
    "details" : {
      "firstName":"My",
      "lastName":"God",
      "enabled": false,
      "id":927878192,
      "language":"en_US",
    }
  }
}
```

I am having a Details class with the `getter` and `setter` methods for `firstName`, `lastName`, `enabled`, `id` and `language`.

The class is annotated with `@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)`.

However I don't want to show `language` and `enabled` in JSON response.

So in my java code, I did the following for `language`:

`details.setLanguage(null);`

That worked fine.

But I can't do `details.setEnabled(null)` because the `enabled` variable is primitive that can take `true` or `false` but not `null`. So my JSON response always has `"enabled": false`.

What can be done so that this field will not be a part of JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use `@JsonIgnore` annotation on field level.
For example:

```
@JsonIgnore
private boolean isActive;
```

Comment: what if my another API want to show `isActive` in response? This annotation will ignore the field from its response as well?

Comment: Read my other response. With the annotation specified there you will be able to get what you want. :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to ignore the property only for selected response I suggest using `@JsonView` from `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation` package but it could be an overkill.

First you need to create a class with an interface inside:

```
public class View {
    public interface UserDetailed {}
}
```

After that you specify in your class which field should be visible only for specific 'profile':

```
public class User {
    // Other fields
    @JsonView(View.UserDetailed.class)
    private List<Role> roleCollection = new ArrayList<Role>();
    // Other fields, getters and setters
}
```

Then on the controller's method that needs to display that property you do:

```
@Controller
public class UserController{
    @RequestMapping(value = "/userWithRoles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    @JsonView(View.UserDetailed.class)
    public User getUserWithRoles() {…} 

    @RequestMapping(value = "/userWithoutRoles", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public User getUserWithoutRoles() {…} 
}
```

The result is: only the controller methods that have the same @JsonView as the field will display it. Other will ignore it. It allows you to manage the visibility of the fields depending on the use case.

Here you can read more about it:
http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews

Comment: In which class should I specify a field that needs to be visible - View class OR bean class? I tried to specify in view class but its still visible to all APIs.

Comment: I've edited the post. Check it out. :) In your case the field should be annotated in `Details` class.

Comment: what should be the package of @JsonView annotation of User class and UserController class? I used `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView` for `UserController` and `org.codehaus.jackson.map.annotate.JsonView` for User. Then ran the API and it is giving 404 Not Found.

Comment: Both should be from the same package. I suggest using `com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonView` .

Answer (score 0):

Put `@JsonIgnore` on the `enabled` getter method.

If you want to ignore it only during serialization but you need it when deserializing (if you need to edit that field from some method of the REST API), you can annotate with `@JsonSetter("enabled")` the enabled setter method.

Example:

```
public class Details {
    ....
    private boolean enabled;

    ...

    @JsonIgnore
    public boolean isEnabled()

    @JsonSetter
    public void setEnabled(boolean enabled)

}
```

If you for some API method need enabled and for others no, the cleanest way to do so is to have two DTOs:

```
public class DetailsBasic {
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private long id;

    // getters and setters
}


public class Details extends DetailsBasic {
    private boolean enabled;
    private boolean language;

    // getters and setters
}
```

And then in your controller:

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/user", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
DetailsBasic user(@RequestParam("username") 
String username, @RequestParam("password") String password)  {
    return ...
}

@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value="/otherMethod", method = {RequestMethod.POST})
Details otherMethod(@RequestParam("username") 
String username, @RequestParam("password") String password)  {
    return ...
}
```